# Change font color of headers in Zim Wiki

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, gtk-windows, zim

[This mail archive entry](https://www.mail-archive.com/zim-wiki@lists.launchpad.net/msg02768.html) describes how one can edit `style.conf` to change the color of headers in Zim Wiki.

1. Enter the color you like:

   ```
   [Tag h1]
   foreground=#b20000
   ```
2. Save the changes, close and reopen Zim Wiki, and you should be good.

However, nothing changes for me. I was wondering if this might be an issue with the Windows version? The mail archive entry mentions that on Ubuntu the file should be located at `home/user/.config/zim/style.conf`.

On Windows 10 with Zim Wiki 0.67, I have two such files, one in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Zim Desktop Wiki/share/zim/style.conf` and another in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Zim Desktop Wiki/data/style.conf`. Changes to these files do not show up after reopening Zim.

**Edit**:
Indeed, [the manual](http://zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Config_Files.html) says to "copy `/usr/share/zim/style.conf` to `~/.config/zim/`". However I am not sure what this means for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Raphaël Doré](https://github.com/raphaeldore) kindly pointed out on [github](https://github.com/jaap-karssenberg/zim-desktop-wiki/issues/218), `style.conf` should be placed in `C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\zim\config\zim`. Changes will apply after closing and reopening zim.

Note that this worked for me, while for Raphaël the file had to be placed at `C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\zim\config\zim\profiles\Notes`